Reference request for $\sum_{f(x_i)=0}\mid x_i\mid$
I'm looking for a paper detailing, or someone referring to the quantity
$$\sum_{f(x_i)=0}\mid x_i\mid$$
which is the sum of the absolute value/magnitude of all roots of $f(x)$, a polynomial $\in \mathbb{C}$. Obviously Vieta's formula doesn't apply here, and I haven't been able to find this in literature. Aditionally any advice as to a way to study this quantity as I honestly have no idea as of now. Thank you for your time

Are you looking for this quantity with respect to the sizes of the coefficients of $f(x)$? Or with some other measuring stick?

@Integrand Sorry I don't understand why the approach needs to be relative to another metric, unless you mean like how Vieta's formula is...? Any approach helps, and your suggestion would yield an interesting angle of study

I guess I'm confused; if you're just interested in the sum of the magnitudes of the roots, this can clearly be unbounded, even for low-degree polynomials ($f(x) = x-m;|m|$, $f(x) = x^2-n;2|\sqrt{n}|$, etc.). That's why I thought to "normalize" the quantity you seek with respect to the size of the coefficients of $f$.

@Integrand Ah I see, that would be wise thank you. Sizes of coefficients would be a good 'measuring stick' as heights and lengths of polynomials are well-studied.

Additionally I'm interested in polynomials whose coefficients are small $\in [-1, 1]$.

Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots; in particular, perhaps Landau's Inequality (taking logs) is helpful.
